# Solving a tough equation involving integer functions

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ceiling-and-floor-functions

I am stuck on solving the equation, given $k\lt\frac{n}{2},\ n,k\ge3$:
$$ m=\lceil 2k-\frac{2}{n}\displaystyle\left(\lfloor\frac{n-\lfloor\frac{n}{k+1}\rfloor}{2}\rfloor\right)(k+1)\rceil$$.

I think the value of $m$ would be $k$. But, the detailed solution is beyond my reach. What inequalities and analysis should we use to reach the solution? Also, what if I modify the equation to:
$$m=\lceil 2\frac{nk}{n-1}-\frac{2}{n-1}\displaystyle\left(\lfloor\frac{n-\lfloor\frac{n}{k+1}\rfloor}{2}\rfloor\right)(k+1)\rceil$$
Will the value of $m=k+1$ at any value of $n,k$? Any hints Thanks beforehand.

Comment: When $n=1$, the value is $2k$. I would try a few values to see what you get.

Comment: @MPW thanks, but I've edited my question

Comment: Are $n$ and $k$ integers? Nonnegative? Positive?

Comment: @MPW yes, I have added that in the question now. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We calculate the first expression for integer values $k\geq 0, n\geq 1$.

> Let $a,b$ be non-negative integer with
> \begin{align*}
>   n=a(k+1)+b\qquad\quad a,b\geq 0,\ \  0\leq b<k+1\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}
> we obtain
> \begin{align*}
>  \color{blue}{ a(n,k)}
>   &\color{blue}{=\left\lceil 2k-\frac{2}{n}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n-\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k+1}\right\rfloor}{2}\right\rfloor\right)(k+1)\right\rceil}\\
>  &=\left\lceil2k-\frac{2}{n}\left(\left\lfloor\frac{n-a}{2}\right\rfloor\right)(k+1)\right\rceil\tag{2}\\
>   \end{align*}

Here we use (1) to get $\left\lfloor\frac{n}{k+1}\right\rfloor=\left\lfloor\frac{a(k+1)+b}{k+1}\right\rfloor=a+\left\lfloor\frac{b}{k+1}\right\rfloor=a$ noting that $0\leq b<k+1$.

In (2) we consider two cases: $n-a$ even or odd.

> **Case 1:** $n-a$ even
>
> We obtain from (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a(n,k)}
> &=\left\lceil2k-\frac{2}{n}\left(\frac{n-a}{2}\right)(k+1)\right\rceil\\
> &=\left\lceil2k-\left(\frac{n-a}{n}\right)(k+1)\right\rceil\\
> &=\left\lceil2k-\left(1-\frac{a}{n}\right)(k+1)\right\rceil\\
> &=\left\lceil k-1+\frac{a(k+1)}{n}\right\rceil\\
> &=\left\lceil k-1+\frac{n-b}{n}\right\rceil\tag{3}\\
> &=\left\lceil k-\frac{b}{n}\right\rceil\\
> &\color{blue}{=}\begin{cases}
> \color{blue}{k}&\color{blue}{\qquad n>k}\\
> \color{blue}{k-1}&\color{blue}{\qquad n\leq k}\tag{4}
> \end{cases}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (3) we use again the representation (1).
- In (4) we observe from (1) that $n=b$ if $n\leq k$ so that $\left\lceil k-\frac{b}{n}\right\rceil=\left\lceil k-1\right\rceil=k-1$.

> **Case 2:** $n-a$ odd
>
> We obtain from (2)
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{a(n,k)}
> &=\left\lceil2k-\frac{2}{n}\left(\frac{n-a-1}{2}\right)(k+1)\right\rceil\\
> &=\left\lceil2k-\left(\frac{n-a-1}{n}\right)(k+1)\right\rceil\\
> &=\left\lceil2k-\left(1-\frac{a+1}{n}\right)(k+1)\right\rceil\\
> &=\left\lceil k-1+\frac{a(k+1)}{n}+\frac{k+1}{n}\right\rceil\\
> &=\left\lceil k-\frac{b}{n}+\frac{k+1}{n}\right\rceil\\
> &=k+\left\lceil \frac{k+1-b}{n}\right\rceil\\
> &\,\,\color{blue}{=k+1}\\
> \end{align*}

The last line follows since from (1) we have $b<k+1$.

Comment: fantastic! this is what I expected. Actually, this arose from a problem on total coloring of graphs

Comment: @vidyarthi: Thanks for your nice comment. You might be able to calculate the second expression in a similar way.

Comment: Are you sure your arguments are considering the parity of $n-a$? I think it should be $n-b$ right?

Comment: @vidyarthi: In case 1 for instance we can omit the floor function in the first line since $n-a$ is even.

Comment: ok, got it! But does not the parity of $n$ matter here, because I have a conjecture proposed in graph coloring which reduces to the fact that the above value is $k$ when $n>2k$ and $n$ is even. So shall I attack the conjecture or your argument holds good for any parity of $n$

Comment: @vidyarthi: I think it's valid for any parity.

Answer (score 0):

(not a real answer, but formatting doesn't allow as a comment)

I made the following Python code:

```
import math

def calculate(n,k):
    aux = math.floor((n- math.floor(n/(k+1)))/2)
    return math.floor(2*k - 2/n * aux * (k+1)) +1 


for n in range(3,25):
    for k in range(3, n/2):
        print "n/k/m = ", n , "/", k ,",", calculate(n,k) -2 * k - 1
```

And it definitely looks like $m = 2k+1$ in the first case.

Comment: In the part of `return math.floor(2*k-2/n* aux * (k+1)) +1`, why did you put $+1$ in the end?

Comment: Because floor +1 is equal to the ceiling.

Comment: but, by using the inequality $\lfloor x\rfloor\le x$, I am getting $m\le k$ in the first case!

Comment: just try substituting $k=3$, and $n=8$, you get $m=3$, i.e. what is `calculate(8,3)`?

Comment: floor +1  is not always equal to ceiling use math.ceil instead.

Comment: @MattiP. : If $x$ is integral, then $\lfloor x\rfloor=x =\lceil x\rceil$. Otherwise,  $\lfloor x\rfloor<x <\lceil x\rceil= \lfloor x\rfloor + 1$.

Comment: your answer on the probable value of $m$ is wrong. See the accepted answer. Although the code seems to be correct except the ceiling part